# Maximum absolute difference of array values with index sum

Tags: java, python, c, algorithm, data-structures

I got into a problem and it is:
You are given an array of N integers, A1, A2 ,…, AN. Return maximum value of f(i, j) for all 1 ≤ i, j ≤ N.
f(i, j) is defined as |A[i] - A[j]| + |i - j|, where |x| denotes absolute value of x.
For example,

```
A=[1, 3, -1]
f(1, 1) = f(2, 2) = f(3, 3) = 0
f(1, 2) = f(2, 1) = |1 - 3| + |1 - 2| = 3
f(1, 3) = f(3, 1) = |1 - (-1)| + |1 - 3| = 4
f(2, 3) = f(3, 2) = |3 - (-1)| + |2 - 3| = 5
So, we return 5. I have searched for the efficient solution to this problem and that is:

def maxDistance(array):
    # max and min variables as described
    # in algorithm.
    max1 = -2147483648
    min1 = +2147483647
    max2 = -2147483648
    min2 = +2147483647
    for i in range(len(array)):
        # Updating max and min variables
        # as described in algorithm.
        max1 = max(max1, array[i] + i)
        max2 = max(max2, array[i] - i)
        min1 = min(min1, array[i] + i)
        min2 = min(min2, array[i] - i)
    return max(max1 - min1, max2 - min2)
```

Now my question is why we are doing a[i] -i for each value in array. I tried to understand it for many times but still i could not get why we are doing minus with every value with its index value. I need a simple term to understand it. Please help me guys to understand this problem in simple term. i will be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (A[i] > A[j])
   |A[i] - A[j]| = A[i] - A[j];
else
   |A[i] - A[j]| = A[j] - A[i];

if (i > j)
   |i - j| = i - j;
else
    |i - j| = j - i;

==> f(i, j) = (A[i] - A[j] + i - j) || ( A[i] - A[j] + j - i) || (A[j] - A[i] + i - j) ||( A[j] - A[i] + j - i)
==> f(i, j) = (A[i] + i) - (A[j] + j) || (A[i] - i) - (A[j] - j) || (A[j] - j) - (A[i] - i) || (A[j] + j) - (A[i] + i)
```

I think it's clear for you

Comment: Hi hitokiri, thanks for the response. i got these two points |A[i] - A[j]| = A[i] - A[j] and  |A[i] - A[j]| = A[j] - A[i] could you please explain it with example which can make me clear why we are doing this.

Comment: As you see on my answer, `f(i, j)` always is equal to `(a - b)` with the value of `a`  is `A[i] - i` or `A[i] + i` (`b` is the same) . So, max f(i,j) = max(a) - min (b).

Comment: So does it mean when finding the maximum difference of absolute values we don't care about their signs. so one time we add the index with values and find max(min(a[i]+i) - min(a[j]+j)) and other time we minus the index values with array values and find again max(min(a[i]-i) - min(a[j]-j)) because we just need bigger value ignoring signs as we are using absolute difference.

Comment: I just say in your case, if `f = a - b`, `max (f) = max (a) - min (b)`. As i mentioned above, `f` always equals to `a - b`, So we calculate `f(i,j)` as you said. Don't apply difference solution to different problem.